# Make distance thinner in solid gauge amchart4

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts4

**expected**
[image: expected]

**current**
[image: current]

I want to narrow the gap between each lines like in the expected picture. Can you guys help me, thanks a lot. Here is my code, pls give me advices
This is my code.

I dont know this is the gap between axes or between series. And also Im confusing about how to apply color to this chart instead of using the default(this code is from the demo of the amchart library).

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);

chart.data = [{
  "category": "Research",
  "value": 60,
  "full": 100,
  "color": "#1B85FF"
}, {
  "category": "Marketing",
  "value": 15,
  "full": 100,
  "color": "#0CD3D6"
}, {
  "category": "Distribution",
  "value": 60,
  "full": 100,
  "color": "#7449EE"
}];

chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(20);
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0;
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 100;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 0;

var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueX = "full";
series1.dataFields.categoryY = "category";
series1.clustered = false;
series1.columns.template.fill = new am4core.color('#131A22')
series1.columns.template.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 20;
series1.columns.template.strokeWidth = 0;
series1.columns.template.radarColumn.cornerRadius = 20;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueX = "value";
series2.dataFields.categoryY = "category";
series2.clustered = false;
series2.columns.template.strokeWidth = 0;
series2.columns.template.tooltipText = "{category}: [bold]{value}[/]";
series2.columns.template.radarColumn.cornerRadius = 20;
series2.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
});
chart.cursor = new am4charts.RadarCursor();
```

In conclude, I need to increase the gap and change the color of the chart. Wish you all have a good day, thanks a lot.
In conclude, I need to increase the gap and change the color of the chart. Wish you all have a good day, thanks a lot.
In conclude, I need to increase the gap and change the color of the chart. Wish you all have a good day, thanks a lot.
In conclude, I need to increase the gap and change the color of the chart. Wish you all have a good day, thanks a lot.In conclude, I need to increase the gap and change the color of the chart. Wish you all have a good day, thanks a lot.In conclude, I need to increase the gap and change the color of the chart. Wish you all have a good day, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post your code, so that we have a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: sorry for late reply, this is my first time upload post to stackoverflow, I faced an error when editing this post so I duplicated the des a lot xd